# Como escapar espacios en curl -F file1=@${archivo} $urldestino

Tags: php, bash, curl

tengo un problema utilizando la api de verystream. 
el codigo es el siguiente

```
$archivo = $GLOBALS['nameFile'];
// subir contenido
$output = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.verystream.com/file/ul?login=".$user."&key=".$pass), true);
$urldestino = $output['result']['url'];

$download = `curl -F file1=@sh/files/$archivo $urldestino`;
```

**Este codigo funciona bien si el nombre del archivo no tiene espacios.**

Alguna idea? de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Pon el nombre entre comillas dobles de todo lo que quieras que se preserve independientemente de los espacios.

Comment: Eso fue lo primero que hice, pero al parecer va mas allá de las comillas.